# How to encode a link+display message with Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, hyperlink

I am looking to protect my theme author links from being removed.
Most people already know how to remove base64 and rot13 links so I need something more advanced.

How can I encrypt a footer link using javascript + display a message or break the theme if the link is removed?

I am new to JS.
I already read this page: [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) but as I am new to JS I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: The question you link to is about build a URL programatically and including arbitrary data in it without breaking the URL. It has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot make sure that the links aren't removed. It is always possible to delete the something, that prints the links or that breaks the theme, if the link is removed.

Therefore the best way is IMO to make the links acceptable for people, who use your theme.

If you really want to make your users problems, you can either somehow make your CSS depend on the link, or provide an important Javascript file with a subtle and difficult to find check, whether the link is present or not.